# Lower bound on Gram determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a lower bound for the determinant of the Gram matrix when the elements are linearly independent? I am talking about Hilbert space setting not just vectors. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1328684/determinant-of-gram-matrix-lower-bound-and-mistakes